# Notification bubble on admin panel menu if new user added using php ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How can i add notification bubble like Facebook in my admin menu (when new user is signup) by using Ajax php also after viewing/clicking the menu bubble disappear.Anybody help???

Comment: do you want this to update automatically when you're on the admin menu page? If so, you need to use websockets. Otherwise, I can give you the general order of idea that I would do as an answer.

Comment: No i just need if new user added notification bubble will view on the menu and when click the menu it disappear

Comment: I answered your question, is it ok for you?

Comment: thank you .yes i got idea from your answer and sorry for late..

Comment: Good, so is it working?

Comment: yes .Again thank you. Can you help me little more ?? I want to view (new) notification on every newly inserted user row on my table.

Comment: So the notification appears automatically, without refreshing the page. If so, you'll have to look at websockets.

Comment: yes notification appears automatically and everything is ok. can u little bit explain me how can i work with websockets?? i just need notification on each row if new user inserted.

Comment: I've never worked with websockets unfortunately. I just know that's what you're looking for

Comment: it's ok. Anyway thanks

Comment: Is it working ? @Riyadh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user signs up, I guess you add him/her in your database? If so, I would add a field in your `users` database called "notificationViewed", which would be `false` by default when you put that user in the database.

When you connect or refresh you admin menu page, your php that serves the page should check the database if any user has a field `notificationViewed == false`, and `COUNT` the number of such returned users. In your html tag that represents the buble, add an attribute `data-newUsers="<?= COUNT_OF_NEW_USERS ?>"`.

Now on the client-side...

Have, let's say, `id="bubble"` hidden by default with CSS:

```
#bubble {
    display:none;
}
```

With JavaScript, you can access the `data-*` attributes easily:

```
var newUsers = document.getElementById('bubble').dataset.newUsers; // holds the number
```

or with jQuery:

```
var newUsers = $('#bubble').data('newUsers'); // same thing
```

At this point, you can check if `newUsers > 0`. If so, populate the bubble with the number (if you want), and do a nice `fadeIn` animation. Example in jQuery:

```
if (newUsers > 0) {
    $('bubble').text(newUsers).fadeIn();
}
```

Now, we want to be able to detect when the bubble is clicked, in order to hide the bubble and discard the new users signed up. Again, with jQuery:

```
$('#bubble').click(function() {
    $.post('discardNotifications.php', {usersNotified: newUsers}, function(data) {
        if (data === "ok") { // php script returns this string if all went right
            $('#bubble').fadeOut(function() {
                $('#bubble').remove(); // remove the element from the DOM, to prevent further clicks of the element
            }); // nice fadeOut animation of the bubble      
        }
    }
});
```

The function will only be called if the `POST` request was successful. The `POST` request is directed to `discardNotifications.php`, which must be in the same directory as your admin-menu html file (if not, just change the relative path). The second parameter of the call is a litteral object containing the number of new users notified, which is sent to your back-end.

Back on the back-end, inside `discardNotifications.php`...

You must check if there's a `POST` parameter called "usersNotified", then query your `users` database and update at most the number given by "usersNotified". This takes into account that maybe new users subscribed since you refreshed your admin page, and you want the notification of these new users. Not selecting a maximum of "usersNotified" would possibly ignore them. Example (but not complete):

```
if (isset($_POST['usersNotified']))
{
   $number = $_POST['usersNotified'];

   // update the "notificationViewed" field to TRUE for at most $number different users

   echo "ok"; // everything went right
} else {
    echo "bad";
}
```

There are obviously changes you can make, and you have to implement some of the database handling. Tell me if it works!

Ps: there might be little errors in my code snippets, I didn't test everything.